# Proof of information-theoretic approach of likelihood calculation of Bayes Nets

Tags: bayesian, information-theory, mutual-information

I am trying to understand the proof of the scoring function (log likelihood) of a graph $G$ of a Bayes Network given in [this slide](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~guestrin/Class/10701/slides/structurelearn-clustering.pdf). Given a Bayes Net $G$, the log likelihood of data $D$ can be expressed as :

$log L(G|D) = m \sum_i^n(I_{P}(X_i,Pax_i) - H(x_i))$

but the derivation seems very confusing to me. Can anyone break it down to simple terms? Thanks!